# Liferay Error in Staging: MethodInvocationException

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, staging

I modified settings for a Community Site inside Liferay.
Trying to poke and play with Liferay's CMS.
Added this setting= Staging: Remote Live

And now I get this error:

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of
>   method 'runtime' in class com.liferay.taglib.util.VelocityTaglib threw
>   exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   ServletException in '/html/portlet/staging_bar/view.jsp':
>   com.liferay.portal.NoSuchLayoutSetBranchException: No LayoutSetBranch
>   exists with the key {groupId=13309, privateLayout=false, master=true}
>   at VM_liferay.vm[line 91, column 24]

Can anyone help with what can I change programmatically to be able to get into the app again? I cannot even get to localhost:8080, it gives me this error.

I'm still using the default HSQL database.

think it might be related to this: http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-18606

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the one we had some time ago.

Site crashed after modifying it's settings in Control Panel. After some investigation we've found up that a setting branchingPublic=true affected that.

First of all, find out which site (community) have You modified. For example it is "community1".

In database find the row of this site:

```
SELECT * FROM group_ WHERE friendlyurl like '%community1%'
```

And check there what settings it has in column: "typesettings". I recommend copy them to have a backup.

We have changed `branchingPublic=true` to `branchingPublic=false`. And restarted the Liferay Portal.

It helped to start running again.

Although Liferay Support didn't reproduce this, I believe it may help You or someone else.

If that doesn't help, try playing with other settings, maybe some other affects the crash. At last you can try remove them all. Just an idea for You!

Kind Regards!

Comment: thanks krissoko for your answer, I later found out that this issue was caused in my local because I had checked the checkbox for remote staging = live. I ended up dropping and recreating the liferay database to fix this.

Comment: Glad it didn't lead to bigger problems for You. We had this problem in our production DB.